# Closest equivalent to the Chinese jocular use of 职业病 (occupational disease): job creates habits that manifest inappropriately outside work

Tags: phrase-requests, translation, colloquialisms, humor, chinese

The Chinese expression [职业病](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E8%81%8C%E4%B8%9A%E7%97%85) (*zhi ye bing*, occupational disease), when used seriously, just means occupational disease, e.g. lung problems caused by working in a chemical factory.

But there is also a humorous use of the expression, which describes how a person's job creates habits that manifest outside work, usually inappropriately.

For example:

> David is a taxi driver. Sometimes when he is off-work driving his private car, he sees someone standing on the side of the road and, without thinking, he slows down and starts pulling over towards the person. Then he realizes that he's not on the job, does a face palm and says to himself, "职业病!".

Or:

> Jane is a flight attendant. Her job involves the use of a lot of detailed checklists (for safety equipment, boarding procedures, meal apparatus, etc.). At home, her young son would often forget to bring this or that to school, so she made a professional-looking, over-the-top checklist and posted it next to the door. Visitors are always amused by the checklist; she explains it as a case of "职业病".

Or:

> Sofia is a middle school math teacher. A friend texts her, "I turn 50 tomorrow - half a century!" She responds, "1/2 century? You look like more like 3/7 century! Oh sorry, 职业病!".

**What is the closest equivalent of this expression in English?** (It doesn't have to be one word.)

Comment: Answers-in-comments deleted and comments locked: this question seems clear. If you have an answer, **write an answer.**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The most straightforwardly similar term is "occupational hazard", which is frequently used this way (in my experience).

Bruce Sterling writes in his book "[The Hacker Crackdown](https://www.amazon.ca/Hacker-Crackdown-Disorder-Electronic-Frontier/dp/055356370X)":

> Besides, science fiction people are used to being misinterpreted.
>  Science fiction is a colorful, disreputable, slipshod occupation,
> full of unlikely oddballs, which, of course, is why we like it.
>  Weirdness can be an **occupational hazard** in our field.  People who
> wear Halloween costumes are sometimes mistaken for monsters.

In "[The Geometry of Ecological Interactions](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/geometry-of-ecological-interactions/78ABF74F154A2639EDA0A7E135C9B0F1)" we have:

> If the "**occupational hazard**" of being a field ecologist is thinking
> that everything is important and therefore must be included, the
> **occupational hazard** of theoreticians is building general, abstract
> models without a clear goal other than exploring the dynamics of the
> model itself.

From Emily Richards' "[Somewhere between Luck and Trust](https://www.amazon.ca/Somewhere-Between-Luck-Trust-Goddesses-ebook/dp/B01G1G19X8)":

> There’s a phrase.” She tried to recall it and couldn’t.
> “Occupational...”
> “Hazard?” Analiese supplied.
> “That’s the one. Assuming somebody’s lying. Is that an **occupational hazard** of being a minister?”
> Analiese looked as if she was trying not to smile. “My **occupational hazard** is trying to read people’s minds, to see if they
> need help telling more of the truth. I have a feeling you have things
> buried deep inside you that you can’t share with anybody yet. Things
> eating at you.

”

From [The Herald (Scotland)](https://www.heraldscotland.com/opinion/20061194.mark-eadie-brian-coxs-swearing-habit-occupational-hazard/),

> Is Brian Cox's swearing habit an occupational hazard?
>
> Succession star Brian Cox says role has made him swear 'a lot' in real life

In Captain America: Civil War, Tony Stark overreacts to someone removing something from their purse, and then to explain his overreaction he says "Sorry, it's an occupational hazard."

Comment: The quote refers to the  unconventional behaviour that is perceived in "science fiction" people. The author is saying that being *mistaken as weird* is an occupational hazard in their line of work. It's not the same situation which is described by the OP.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I read it as *being* weird (weirdness) is the occupational hazard. In any case I'll add another example.

Comment: I think this is the phrase I've heard. Another example is when a psychotherapist is at a normal social gathering, and can't help analyzing the people they're conversing with.

Comment: Hmm... even if you have succeeded to find a source which mirrors the OP's scenario; people, most, will interpret it differently. An occupational hazard is a risk to one's health which is *normally* present in the workplace. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/occupational-hazard

Comment: I would suggest that an Occupational Hazard might include knock-on effects that carry over into your daily life, but it's generally not associated with your work-behaviour carrying over. I'm not convinced this is the right answer.

Comment: "Occupational hazard" is pretty close to the Chinese expression. Perhaps the main difference is that the Chinese expression is an everyday phrase used by people of all walks of life, whereas "occupational hazard" feels like a somewhat sophisticated expression. But the meaning and usage are very similar.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's almost figurative or hyperbole but it's not that uncommon, it's even in a Marvel movie.

Comment: An 'occupational hazard' for doctors is smoking cigarettes. Use *scare* quotes because it's (unfortunately, only sort of) a joke and not actually on the list of [Occupational hazards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupational_hazard). Used for anything *not* on that list, then it's likely jocular use. *"which is frequently used this way"* +1.

Comment: I pedantically hazard that 'occupational hazard' is a deeply entrenched malapropism for when people might often be more precise if they were to use the phrase 'occupational habit'.  An occupational hazard always happens at work.  An occupational habit can happen anywhere.

Comment: @Muqo I don't think that's the case. The idea is that you are ``at risk for" certain behaviors because your profession or trade encourages certain modes of thought or repeated actions.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That's the literal definition. In my experience as a native speaker of American English, this answer is spot-on for the quite common humorous figurative use of the phrase (of which many examples are supplied in the answer.) I can't speak for the other side of the pond, but I'd guess that this usage of "occupational hazard" is more common in American English, at least in regular day-to-day conversation, than the literal one is.

Comment: @Muqo It isn't a malapropism, but rather a very intentional humorous usage with the exact same meaning as OP described for the Chinese phrase. It isn't meant to be _precise_; it's meant to be funny. At least here in the U.S., it's often (though not always) used in self-deprecating humor, such as the "Weirdness can be an occupational hazard in our field" quote in the answer.

Comment: In fact, the similarity with the Chinese is so profound that it strongly suggests a common origin.

Answer (score 17):

In English, in a conversation, we can say "Sorry, work habit" followed by a sheepish smile or "(It's) just a work habit". It's difficult to find written usages as it is mainly conversational. The phrase *occupational habit* is used also, instead of *work habit*.

Here is a written example I've found in a story:

> "I know exactly who you are," he paused and I couldn't help but hold my breath under his arresting gaze. "You're... *a psychotherapist.*"
>
> My chest deflated in a long relieved sigh as my shoulders slumped.
>
> "You're right," I gave a nervous chuckle. "You got me. Guilty!" I raised my hands to my sides.
>
> "This is why you asked me about my time in college," his eyes refused to look away from mine. "You're analyzing me."
>
> "**It's just a work habit, you know?** Can't seem to shake it off," I shrugged nonchalantly, fidgeting with my straw.
>
> *[wattpad.com](https://www.wattpad.com/772831099-hearteater-kth-4-personal-hell/page/3)*

Comment: "Work habit" is very close, +1. ("Work habit" is a bit closer than "occupational habit", because "work habit" is more informal - the Chinese expression is used lightheartedly.)

Answer (score 8):

I have encountered the expression ***professional reflex*** referring to the situation you describe. E.g.

> *The White Tiger* is a story of servitude, resentment and love – and what its hero calls “the contented smile that comes to the lips of a servant who has done his duty by his master”. He does a lot of smiling in this film, but this is about something other than contentment. ***It is a professional reflex*** and a personal holding pattern, a blank grin kept in place while the servant decides if he in fact hates his master, and while he also decides if he might somehow one day be the master himself. (*[The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2021/jan/05/the-white-tiger-review-balzac-worthy-satire-of-submission-and-power)*, film review)

> Perhaps it's a ***professional reflex***, but it seemed to me to be the equivalent of a person posting -as an April Fool's joke - that they had just suffered a heart attack, were on life-support, and might not make it. ([source](https://bridgewinners.com/article/view/injunction-lifted/))

However, there is also the concept of ***professional deformation*** which is the English version of ***déformation professionnelle***. About this term, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9formation_professionnelle) says:

> ***Déformation professionnelle*** (French: *professional deformation* or *job conditioning*) is *a tendency to look at things from the point of view of one's own profession or special expertise, rather than from a broader or humane perspective*. It is often translated as *professional deformation*, though French *déformation* can also be translated as "distortion". The implication is that professional training, and its related socialization, often result in a distortion of the way one views the world. The Nobel laureate Alexis Carrel has observed that "every specialist, owing to a well-known ***professional bias***, believes that he understands the entire human being, while in reality he only grasps a tiny part of him."

It is interesting to note that

> "*Déformation professionnelle*" was used in 19th-century medicine to describe a bodily deformity caused by one's occupation.

Just as your Chinese term, I suppose one could use this expression to mean that you do something out of a habit that was instilled in you by your profession.

Comment: "Professional reflex", although not a common phrase (a quick internet search yields nothing for me), would be easily understood in the contexts in question, and it is remarkably close to the Chinese expression, in terms of the feeling. +1

Comment: Yes, it is rare it seems, yet [Ngram seems to find plenty](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=professional+reflex&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprofessional%20reflex%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Cheers. Btw, I would say "a habit that was instilled in you..." instead of "a habit that was induced in you...". (I read your personal intro page - "I am not a native speaker... grateful to be shown my mistakes")

Comment: Indeed, I am grateful. Will edit :)

Comment: To clarify, I wouldn't say "induce" is a mistake; "instill" just seems slightly more natural in that context.

Answer (score 6):

We sometimes refer to “bringing our work home”. In this usage, it refers more to the behaviour than to actual work done for the employer. Here is an example from cartoon stock:

> [Cartoonstock](https://www.cartoonstock.com/directory/b/bring_your_work_home.asp)

[image]

Comment: The cartoon is making fun of the phrase. It's normally used literally for doing real work at home, not the way the OP wants.

Comment: "Bringing one's work home" is similar to the Chinese expression in that both describe a failure to detach oneself from work. But the word "home" weakens from the similarity: the Chinese phrase can be used to describe a person who is anywhere, not just at home.

Comment: At least to me it seems a natural reading that the cartoon character _is_ doing actual work for the employer and the joke is that it's a really inappropriate kind of work to bring home.

Comment: @Alexey Romanov I wonder where you live if you think it is normal to be firing out the window with a semi-automatic gun. If you tried that here you would end up serving a prison sentence. And what sort of employment do you imagine?

Comment: @Anton It isn't normal, but it's the normal amount of non-normal for a New Yorker cartoon. The employment is in mafia (or local equivalent) and treating it as any other job is again part of the joke.

Answer (score 1):

### Work on the brain

Depending on your context the idiom ["On the brain"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20the%20brain) is sometimes used as part of an apology when you have a freudian slip.
"Anyway the crust of the matter is.. hang-on, did I say crust? I meant Crux. I must have pizza on the brain"

You might similarly say refer to having Work "on-the-brain" when you slip into technical jargon at home.

Comment: Not bad, but my impression is that if a person has "work on the brain" then they are thinking about some specific work-related issue (e.g. a teacher thinking about what questions to put on next week's exam), whereas the Chinese expression is about general habits (e.g. a plastic surgeon staring at strangers' noses).

Answer (score 0):

I have always used the term [Force of Habit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/force%20of%20habit).
[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/force_of_habit) has a good definition:

> The tendency for something done very frequently to become automatic.
> "he checks his appearance out of force of habit"

It doesn't specifically refer to a *work* habit; however, most of or time is spent doing work tasks, so this applies.
TBH: It could also be a habit from a previous job, or a learned task, etc.

Comment: Well, ideally the expression should explicitly include the concept of occupation/profession/work.

Comment: @Dan Exactly, I grew up with several older brothers, my 'force of habit' is to, when sitting down to eat, quickly pile a lot of food on my plate. This habit was formed so I wouldn't go hungry, as there would be no opportunity for seconds. This has nothing to do with work.

Answer (score 0):

*zhi ye bing* : occupational disease

*zhi ye* : profession

*bing* : adverb : also, side by side, simultaneously. conjunction : and. verb :
combine, incorporate, merge

– Google Translate

---

***'It comes with the territory.'***
***'It comes with the job.'***

"phrase. If you say that something comes with the territory, you mean that you accept it as a natural result of the situation you are in. Doing human rights work is risky business. That comes with the territory." – [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/come-with-the-territory)

This is the closest *literal* equivalent. But the answer you want is *occupational hazard*. All [occupational diseases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupational_disease) are (coming from the hypernym) [occupational hazards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupational_hazard), but not all occupational hazards are occupational diseases. And diseases are never something to joke about. Like getting herpes from a hooker. But if instead the hooker falls in love with Richard Gere, then that's an 'occupational hazard'.

That the word *bing* somehow got translated to 'disease' is the problem, and the thinking that a *hazard* is always bad. Because *fill in the blank* after the word *occupational* has only one answer : *hazard*.

---

*"a plastic surgeon staring at strangers' noses"*

'If the only tool you have is a hammer, you tend to see every problem as a nail.'

Comment: About the "bing": you've got the wrong "bing"; your bing is "并” but it should be "病", which means illness/disease. Here's my go-to Chinese-English dictionary: https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary  (I wish I could make hyperlinks in comments.)

Comment: Ok, the 'problem' is there's 100 characters, all translated into *bing*. ;) *occupational hazard* is in use, if only seldom.  But I've never heard *occupational disease* in my entire life and was surprised to find it had its own wiki page.

Comment: [Here's the link.](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E7%97%85)